# Is it possible to mimic sliding doors technique in CSS to have buttons without images

Tags: html, css, user-interface

We use the sliding doors technique in CSS with sliced background images as mentioned [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css_oval_buttons/) to create buttons which are oval shaped and have the color change and press down effect.

Would it be possible to do something simmilar just with CSS but without using any background images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can in browsers that support CSS3 property `border-radius` (*[specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-radius)*)

Examples at http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

In css you should use

`a{..}` to style the default style
`a:hover{..}` to style the over effect
`a:active{..}` to style the pressed effect

Comment: How about the press down effect, will it be possible to achieve without images

Comment: @Samual, not sure what the press down effect is.. there is no third state in the example link you gave..

Comment: @Samual the press down effect would be set in the a:active rule by shifting the link's position down and to the right. You could do this with position:relative, top: 1px, left: 1px.

Answer (score -1):

CSS3 property border-radius (specs) its ok.

but it was not working in IE and other browsers so please don't use this preporty and use background-color:#000;
.. but round-cornner not possible.

Thaks 
Ptiwari

Comment: can you let me know, the browser versions you had it successfully running and the ones which didn't